# How to notate a diminished run in G♯ minor?

Tags: chords, notation

I'm trying to transcribe Brothers by Yngwie Malmsteen and have a question regarding the diminished run he does 29 seconds in to the song.

The song is in G♯ minor and he's playing the notes A♯, C♯, E and G, so all the notes that he's playing are in the key - except for G.

My question is: how do I notate the G?

Should I raise a F (which already is sharp), so it becomes double sharp? Or should I put a natural sign before a G?

[image]

Please tell me if something else is wrong, I'm new to writing sheet music.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you'll want to notate this G as F.

There are a few reasons for this, but mainly it's to show how the chord is functioning. Since this is a vii°7 chord, you'll want to build it on the leading tone, which, in G♯ minor, is F.

As it's currently spelled, it looks like a ii°7 (built on A♯), which doesn't actually match the function of that chord.

Comment: Is this what happens?

Yngwie moves from G# minor to G# harmonic minor, thus raising the seventh scale degree, which is the reason to why you don’t lower the G# -> G with at natural sign. It’s the seventh that is raised, so it’s the seventh that needs to be changed. Even thou the F already has a sharp we have no other choice then to add another sharp. He then focuses on the viio7 chord, which represents the alt dominant bb7 mode of the harmonic minor scale and is built from F## as the root, and plays inversions of that chord.
A#, C#, E, F##;
C#, E, F##, A#;
E, F##, A#, C#;
F##, A#, C#, E

Comment: @user51803 Yes, pretty much. Although we don't typically say something moves from one type of minor to another; often we just understand that minor is fluid and can use aspects of any of its forms at any time.